# Open product in new tab

Tags: magento-1.8, product, tabs

I've received the following request from some of the admin users:

When viewing the products list (The Manage Products screen), they want products to open in a new tab when clicking on them to edit.

I'm not sure if it's as simple as setting target="_blank" somewhere or if it's more complex, I honestly am not sure where to start.

Can someone please help me or at least point me in the right direction, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tell them to use middle mouse click for new tab :D.
Now seriously, the edit link is generated in the method `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid::_prepareColumns` with this code:

```
    $this->addColumn('action',
        array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Action'),
            'width'     => '50px',
            'type'      => 'action',
            'getter'     => 'getId',
            'actions'   => array(
                array(
                    'caption' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Edit'),
                    'url'     => array(
                        'base'=>'*/*/edit',
                        'params'=>array('store'=>$this->getRequest()->getParam('store'))
                    ),
                    'field'   => 'id'
                )
            ),
            'filter'    => false,
            'sortable'  => false,
            'index'     => 'stores',
    ));
```

if you make the `actions` section look like this

```
           'actions'   => array(
                array(
                    'caption' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Edit'),
                    'url'     => array(
                        'base'=>'*/*/edit',
                        'params'=>array('store'=>$this->getRequest()->getParam('store'))
                    ),
                    'field'   => 'id', 
                    'target'   => '_blank'
                )
            ),
```

You should get it to open in a new tab.
But don't edit the code. Just rewrite the method.

Comment: Thanks! Just a heads up, isn't it `'target'=>'_blank'`?

Comment: Yep. You are right. I edited the answer. Thanks.